# PyQt write inherit from QWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm about to refactor a messy code of a small GUI and tried combine a few elements into a new class which inherits from QWidget. Sadly, the widget isn't painted, but doesn't produce an error either.

A made a minimal example of the problem:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel


class ExportOptions(QWidget):
    def __int__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        #self.setFixedSize(100,100)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(QLabel("Test"))
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = QMainWindow()
    mainWindow.setCentralWidget(ExportOptions())
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Running the file produces an empty window without the Label.
I think I'm missing something very trivial, but I can't spot it...

I'm using latest `Anaconda2 i.e.` `Python 2.7` and `pyQt 5.8` on a windows machine.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo: `def __int__` should be `def __init__`.

Unrelated: you don't need to call `self.show()` in your `ExportOptions` widget, it will be automatically shown when its parent window is displayed.

Comment: I KNEW it was something stupid... Thanks a lot. looking for hours at the code a missing that point is somehow embarrassing :-(